# My jQuery slideToggle is firing 3x for my first <div> container. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myBtn').click(function () {
        $(".container").add('.container2').slideToggle("slow", function () {
            if ($(".container2").is(':visible'))
                $(".myBtn2").addClass('flip');
            else
                $(".myBtn").removeClass('flip');
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.myBtn').click(function(){
   $(".myBtn2").animate({top: '1602px'}, 1200);
    $(".container2").animate({top: '1600px'}, 1200);
     $(".year2").animate({top: '1600px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn2").animate({top: '1634px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn3").animate({top: '1748px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn4").animate({top: '2083px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn5").animate({top: '2240px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn6").animate({top: '2531px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn7").animate({top: '3042px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn7a").animate({top: '3113px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn7b").animate({top: '3183px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn7c").animate({top: '3253px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn7d").animate({top: '3368px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn8").animate({top: '3437px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn9").animate({top: '3632px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn10").animate({top: '3792px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn11").animate({top: '3861px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn12").animate({top: '4020px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn13").animate({top: '4135px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn14").animate({top: '4248px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn15").animate({top: '4362px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn16").animate({top: '4698px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn17").animate({top: '4768px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn18").animate({top: '4970px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn19").animate({top: '5173px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn20").animate({top: '5367px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn21").animate({top: '5570px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn22").animate({top: '5728px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn23").animate({top: '5930px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn24").animate({top: '6045px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn25").animate({top: '6115px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn26").animate({top: '6229px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn27").animate({top: '6431px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn28").animate({top: '6635px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn29").animate({top: '6748px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn30").animate({top: '6996px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn31").animate({top: '7258px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn32").animate({top: '7416px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn33").animate({top: '7620px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn34").animate({top: '7821px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn35").animate({top: '8112px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn36").animate({top: '8490px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn37").animate({top: '8738px'}, 1200);
       $(".myInnerBtn38").animate({top: '8890px'}, 1200);
  });
});
</script>
```

I believe these are the only codes that may be affected. I don't know which line specifically. It's driving me nuts.

I've tried many suggested ways to fix the problem, such as using

```
.one
```

```
.once
```

```
.stop
```

And another which I can't remember. I just can't figure this out. Done a lot of Google searches on it, and couldn't find anything that relates to my problem.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that *demonstrates* the problem?  Specifically *minimal code* to demonstrate - all those animates seem to be completely unrelated to a single click event - try replacing them all with a `console.log("click1")` (and 2 for the 2nd click)

Comment: @freedomn-m, those animates relate to myInnerBtn. The single click button is the main one I'm having problems with. It's hard for me to make out a minimal reproducible example. Unless you mean, just a short bit of the code that is being affected?

Comment: I have tried different approaches in this bit of the code:

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.myBtn').click(function(){
   $(".myBtn2").animate({top: '1602px'}, 1200);
    $(".container2").animate({top: '1600px'}, 1200);
     $(".year2").animate({top: '1600px'}, 1200);

Hope that helps?

Comment: myBtn is in both scripts I shared. Right after (document).ready(function(). Yes, the click event fires the slideToggle. I have only one <div class="container"> as that's the only one that is being affected. The rest is <div class="container2"> and so on...

Comment: I'm still struggling with this issue. Does anyone know a way out?